# What is the time complexity of the *in* operation on arrays in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, big-o

This code returns the first two numbers in the array that sum up to the targetSum. So for example
`print(twoNumberSum([3, 5, -4, 8, 11, 1, -1, 6],10))` should return `[11,-1]`

```
def twoNumberSum(array,targetSum):
    for i in array:
        remainder = targetSum - i
        if (remainder != i) and (remainder in array):
            return [i,remainder]
    return []
```

The code works but it is said to execute in **O(n)** time. My intuition is this - we first loop through the array and choose a number. For each number, we find the remainder. Using each remainder, we again loop through the entire array. Shouldn't this be an **O(n^2)** operation? Is the **in** operation in python not an **O(n)** operation?

Answer (score 2):

The `in` operation will have different complexities based on the type of container it is referred to. Here `i in array` will become `array.__contains__(i)` and it is referred to a list type container.

- (list, tuple) as you guessed are **O(n)**.
- Trees would be average **O(log n)**.
- set/dict - Average: **O(1)**, Worst: **O(n)**.

See this [Document](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). For the case of an `list`, it makes no sense that this will take less than `O(n^2)` time. The outer loop takes `O(n)` time, and for each iteration `O(n)` time to check if the element is present or not.

If instead of a `list`, you use a `dict`, then the `in` operation is `O(1)`. Then I could say that the whole of this code takes linear time.